# How to upload up 10gb file on ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, upload, web-config

I have done a application on asp.net and I'm saving a video and audio file is sql server 
i have a issue with uploading big file over on sever. appls is hosted on ISS7 here i used a code in web.config file that is a below:

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="3600" maxRequestLength="102400"/>
```

and

```
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>        
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1024000000"/>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

but im getting error on uploading time that is below in image:

[image]

please help me out how can i upload files up to 10GB with ISS7 
10GB file im save ing as a `varbinary(MAX)` and 10GB was converting in Byte

Comment: Isn't `varbinary(MAX)` limited to 2Gb?

Answer (score 3):

With out-of-the-box ASP.NET, you are not going to be able to upload a file that big, because IIS will either timeout or you will exceed the size limitations (read: `maxRequestLength` setting for IIS).

You have a few options:

1. Custom HTTP module

   [NeatUpload](http://neatupload.codeplex.com/) is a free option.
2. Silverlight/Flash option

   [SWFUpload](https://code.google.com/p/swfupload/) is a free option.
3. Asynchronous chunking option

   [RadAsyncUpload - Telerik's ASP.NET AsyncUpload](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/asyncupload/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx) is a pay option, check website for pricing.

Comment: @Vikram - Okay, you need a mechanism to get it to the server, once it is there you can save it to the file system, database, network share, whatever. The built-in ASP.NET IIS limitations on file uploads is going to preclude you from uploading as large as a file as you want, which is why I recommended the solutions above. Are you  holding out hope that it will work with just IIS settings?

Answer (score 1):

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="3600" maxRequestLength="102400"/>
```

is about 10Mb (maxRequestLength is in Kb - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641(v=vs.100).aspx)

You try set it to 10485760...