# system.out of memory exception in file upload

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik, radupload

I want to upload a file size of 1 GB with ASP.NET . I Write This Code

```
 Dim bytes(up_FileImage.UploadedFiles(0).ContentLength) As Byte
                    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath, "App_Data/", ViewState("DirectoreName").ToString(), up_FileImage.UploadedFiles(0).FileName))
                    itemDocFile.FileImage = bytes
```

and in web.config Write this Code

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="102400" executionTimeout="3600"/>
```

but in First Line I Get this Error

```
system.out of memory exception
```

Please Help Me. Thanks All

Comment: default size of IIS is only 4MB, so it will give you error for uploading 1GB size file, try to set the size of file from your webconfig file.

Comment: @  Krunal Patil: I Update Question. Thanks.

Comment: File.ReadAllBytes() means you will load into memory everything. try to avoid this if you can.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to upload up 10gb file on ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904580/how-to-upload-up-10gb-file-on-asp-net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uploading a file that large is unadvisable.  Here's some alternatives:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17904718/902874