# System.OutOfMemoryException error on js file load

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webgrease

`@Scripts.Render()` throws this error;

`An exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in WebGrease.dll but was not handled in user code`

in my layout page when I am trying to include a 10 MB js file. Other scripts are working fine.

Comment: Holy moly that's a big JS file, why on earth do you need that?!

Comment: and what is the size of the other js files?

Comment: Other files are of below 1 MB. I am try to add this js because my client does not like that big DevExpress DXR extension in source code. So I thought I clould just save it as a file and render it through bundles.

Answer (score 0):

First of all this is not really advisable. uploading such huge files is not exactly a great solution. Do consider other methods.

In anyway, here are a few things you could try to solve your problem;

**Solution 1**. If you are running on 64 bit Windows and you have enough free memory, ensure that the platform target is set correctly in the `project properties > build properties`.

**Solution 2**. If you are using .NET 4.5 or greater you can add this line to the runtime section of your App.Config:

```
<runtime> 
   <gcallowverylargeobjects enabled="true"></gcallowverylargeobjects> 
</runtime>
```

**Solution 3**. You could increase the `maxRequestLength`in your web config file.

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="3600" maxRequestLength="102400"/>
```

Let me know if any of this works.

**Reference:**

[1] https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2020006/how-to-troubleshoot-out-of-memory-issues-system-outofmemoryexception-i
[2] https://forums.asp.net/t/1548237.aspx?ASP+NET+2+0+System+out+of+memory+exception
[3] [How to upload up 10gb file on ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904580/how-to-upload-up-10gb-file-on-asp-net/17904718#17904718)
[4] https://systemoutofmemory.com/blogs/the-programmer-blog/c-out-of-memory-exception

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it did not work. Although I am still able to render it through <script> tag. but @Script.Render still throwing the same error.